# How can I change the cursor style in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open VS Code, the **cursor is shown as a block as shown below**, **but I want the cursor to be a single vertical line**. Is it possible to change this in VS Code so that when I use R, Python, or cmd terminals in R, the cursor is constently a single vertical line, not like the current block type cursor?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open Settings via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. Search for "Terminal > Integrated: Cursor Style"
3. Choose "line" from the drop down menu

[image: Terminal Integrated Cursor Style]

Results:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 3):

Open setting(json) find: `"terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "block"` change block to line.

Comment: Other options for this line are: "line" and "underline".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `terminal.integrated.cursorStyle` and `terminal.integrated.cursorStyleInactive` settings. See also the somewhat related `terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking` setting.